# CSS - Avoid resizing of background image on iOS browser after scroll

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I'm currently working on a website in which I'm using a `div` that has a background image in order to maintain the `fixed` attribute even while on iOS. The code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="background" style="background-image: url(bi.jpg);"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#background{
    position:fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:-1;
    display:block;
    background:no-repeat 50% 0%;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

This works great for most viewport sizes, but on the iOS Safari browser the tool bar at the top shrinks when the user scrolls down. That changes the viewport height and the `cover` attribute tries to compensate for this and so it snaps to a slightly new size after the scroll is complete. Is there any way to make sure that the background image is covering the whole screen and won't change after that scroll? This may require some JS but I'm not sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem by making a script that runs when the browser is an iOS safari. It gets the height of the screen and sets the background to that height making it so when the viewport resizes on scroll the whole image doesn't resize but rather continues.

```
function checkSafari(){
    "use strict";
    var height = $(window).height();
    var heightAdd = height + 40;            // add __ px to background height
    var heightAddMore = heightAdd + 30;     // add more for case iphone
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;

    if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
       $("#background").css({"background-size":"auto " + heightAdd +"px"});
    }
    else if(userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
       $("#background").css({"background-size":"auto " + heightAddMore +"px"});
    }
}
```

But this would make the background an incorrect size when the user changes the orientation so I made another function to rerun this function on orientation change.

```
function detectOrientation(){
    "use strict";
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    if(userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)){
        $(window).on("orientationchange", function(event){
            checkSafari();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add `background-attachment: fixed;` to your #background
that should fix it.